# Talend tRESTClient requires Document data type in schema

Tags: java, json, rest, talend

I'm using the tRESTClient  to call a REST service to post a JSON string (with records).  The tRESTClient component does not allow me to use a custom schema that matches my string.  it says:

the method `getDocument()` is undefined for the type String

It seems is trying to execute the `getDocument` against the schema but the input schema is a STRING not a DOCUMENT data type.

If I use a tMAP to try to convert my json String to a Document, I get this error:

> Type Mismatch: cannot convert from String to Document

how does one convert a string to a document? this is a json string such as this:

```
{"names:[{"fname":"edgar"},{"fname":"jose"},{"fname":"peter"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You store your string in json file and then  read data from that json file and use tXMLMap Component to provide input to tRESTClient
tFileInputJson -> tXmlMap -> tRestClien
i hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks Vishnu but I have over 51,000 json messages to upload during peak days so that would mean 51,000 individual files.  Doesn't that complicate the job?

Comment: No Need To Create Individual File For Each Json String You Can Create Single Json File with  json array which contain all Json String's and then you have to read Json's from that file one by one parse json string properly and use it in tXMLMap to Convert it in to Document.